# Parsing JSON and persist it in H2 Database

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, parsing, persistence

I have the following JSON which I need to parse and persist to the H2 database. I am struggling to understand and create a structure for underlying classes/entities with a proper annotations. I wonder if any of you advise me on that.

```
{
  "teams": [
    {
      "positions": [
        {
          "alert": false,
          "altitude": 18,
          "type": "automatic",
          "dtfKm": 0,
          "id": 44148875,
          "gpsAt": "2017-12-07T12:00:00Z",
          "sogKnots": 0,
          "battery": 56,
          "cog": 44,
          "dtfNm": 0,
          "txAt": "2017-12-07T12:02:33Z",
          "longitude": -60.94975,
          "latitude": 14.07726,
          "gpsAtMillis": 1512648000000,
          "sogKmph": 0
        },
        {
          "alert": false,
          "altitude": 12,
          "type": "automatic",
          "dtfKm": 4981.635,
          "id": 43673920,
          "gpsAt": "2017-11-19T11:00:00Z",
          "sogKnots": 0.1,
          "battery": 93,
          "cog": 23,
          "dtfNm": 2689.867,
          "txAt": "2017-11-19T11:00:11Z",
          "longitude": -15.42632,
          "latitude": 28.12884,
          "gpsAtMillis": 1511089200000,
          "sogKmph": 0.4
        },
        {
          "alert": false,
          "altitude": 17,
          "type": "automatic",
          "dtfKm": 4981.635,
          "id": 43672771,
          "gpsAt": "2017-11-19T10:00:00Z",
          "sogKnots": 0,
          "battery": 93,
          "cog": 138,
          "dtfNm": 2689.867,
          "txAt": "2017-11-19T10:00:32Z",
          "longitude": -15.42633,
          "latitude": 28.12882,
          "gpsAtMillis": 1511085600000,
          "sogKmph": 0
        },
        {
          "alert": false,
          "altitude": 10,
          "type": "automatic",
          "dtfKm": 4981.635,
          "id": 43671152,
          "gpsAt": "2017-11-19T09:00:06Z",
          "sogKnots": 0,
          "battery": 94,
          "cog": 151,
          "dtfNm": 2689.867,
          "txAt": "2017-11-19T09:00:16Z",
          "longitude": -15.42635,
          "latitude": 28.12884,
          "gpsAtMillis": 1511082006000,
          "sogKmph": 0
        }
      ],
      "marker": 222,
      "name": "Rock 7",
      "serial": 6251
    }
  ],
  "raceUrl": "test2017"
}
```

Can you recommend a structure for entities to parse it and persist into H2 database?

Answer (score 1):

Following DTO structure should work fine. I have added few fields

```
class Position {

    public boolean alert;
    public String type;
    ...

}

class Teams {

    public String marker;
    public String name;
    public Integer serial;

    public List<Position> positions;

}


class MainDTO {

    public List<Teams> teams;
    public String raceUrl;

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! How is it better to annotate them? Would Teams and Positions be an @Embedded type? Can I use raceUrl as an @id? Or would hibernate persist the data without all that?

Comment: Yes you can use Embedded.  yes you need to add Id for id field for hibernate to mark as primary key

Comment: Thanks. I would be grateful if you can annotate DTO as you see it.